# Is there a way to customise PPD distribution of printer drivers effectively with Mac Os X server?

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, printing, cups

we have two network printers shared via our 10.5.8 Mac Os Server machine. They have drivers provided by the manufacturer that allow job logging (printing with a print code).

I've installed said drivers on the server, but when we distribute the printer on our Mac Os clients (using add printer via bonjour) it deploys older drivers that don't support Job Logging. Is there a way to update the store of print drivers (cups drivers?) on the server so it distributes the updated drivers, rather than the older one?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) to update your client machines and populate presets.  Check out this link for a reasonably effective way to do what you want:

[Defining global printer presets for all users on a MacOS X computer](http://oz-penguin.livejournal.com/4987.html)

Comment: This is a really useful answer, that I'll end up using in the future! I'd upvote you but I don't have the reputation yet. It's not the presets I'm after, but the not-quite-standard cups drivers that the printer manufacturer provided. I want them to be pushed out in the process of adding a new network printer.